# Query for absent and present Employee

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have two tables Employee and Attendance, now i want date wise record both absent and present employee.

Like:--

Table1: Employee (EmpId,Name)

Table2: Attendance (Empid, CheckInOutDateTime, Status (like --I/O))

**(Record will not available when Employee is Absent in Attendance Table but need record)**

Now I want output:

```
**EmpID    Name  Date          Status**

1         Emp1   06/11/2013     Persant

2         Emp2   06/11/2013     Absant

3         Emp3   06/11/2013     Persant

1         Emp1   06/12/2013     Persant

2         Emp2   06/12/2013     absant

3         Emp3   06/12/2013     absant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

```
Select Empid,EmpName,Date1,(
cASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT EMPID FROM Atten AT WHERE T.EMPID=AT.EMPID AND T.date1=AT.Chechout
) then 'Present' Else 'Absent' End )as Status
FROM
(
Select Empid,EmpName,Cast(Chechout as DATE)AS DATE1 from Emp a,(Select Distinct Chechout from Atten) b
) T
```

in ms access-:

```
Select Empid,EmpName,Date1,(iif((SELECT Count(Empid)FROM Atten AT WHERE T.EMPID=AT.EMPID AND T.date1=DateVAlue(AT.Chechout))>0,'Absent','Present')) as Status
FROM(
Select Empid,EmpName,DateVAlue(Chechout) AS DATE1 from Emp a,(Select Distinct DateValue(Chechout) as Chechout  from Atten) b
 )T
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7d4e/13)

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi try now i forget to remove end from acess query,,,i edityed it try now

Comment: i already remove END from query but still throwing Syntax error (indicating status)...

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi try is null inplace of exists

Comment: @AmitWe are missing ")" after 'Absent'. thanks for the quick reply and solution. below is complete query:                                                                                                                  Select distinct empid,empName,Date1,(
iif( EXISTs(
SELECT empID FROM Atten AT WHERE T.empID=AT.empID AND T.date1=format(AT.Chechout,'mm/dd/yyyy') 
) , 'Present' , 'Absent'  ))as Status
FROM
(
Select empid,empName,format(Chechout,'mm/dd/yyyy')  AS DATE1 from emp a,(Select Distinct Chechout from Atten ) b
) T order by date1

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi welcome....and thanks for finding very small mistake...i edited my answer as you suggested...

Comment: Not working for me , it duplicate the days of present

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.EmpId,A.Name,B.CheckInOutDateTime,status = CASE WHEN B.STATUS = 'IN' THEN 'PRESENT'
ELSE 'ABSENT' END from Table1 A join Table2 B ON A.Empid=B.empid
```

Comment: There is no record to link to if the employee was absent.

Comment: But in the result set you will find NULL values for the employees who are absent ..

Comment: Ahmed, you won't get any null values, because there's no dates to feed the records. If you don't believe me, test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL feature you are looking for is called an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join). You may also want to read up on the other SQL features.

If for whatever reason you cannot use an outer join, you can use a subselect and count the records in the attendance table because you are only interested in a boolean value, either there or not there for a given day (count > 0, employee was present, count = 0, employee was absent).

Comment: He's doing this for all dates at once, which would require a table with all dates.

Comment: In practice, the distinct date column would probably be enough because there will be no date when *everyone* was absent (that would be like Schroedingers Office or something), but I would implement it like you described, too.

Answer (score 0):

I could probably write a fancy query to get the results you want, but it would also require a 3rd table with every possible date.

I think it would be easier to have a scheduled task that added the absent records at the end of each day. Or you can make everyone absent ahead of time, then change the record to present as the employee shows up.

Comment: Hi Tom, This is not possible that we have maintain 3rd table for absent Employee(for one field(Date)).Main query is show date wise all employee (Absent or present).

Comment: No, a 3rd table is for every single date if you wanted a strictly SQL solution. My suggestion is to write present AND absent records into the  Attendance table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code:

```
for each date as varDate
   query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Employee te LEFT JOIN Attendance ta ON te.Empid = ta.Empid WHERE ta.CheckInOutDateTime = " + varDate.ToString() + " GROUP BY te.Empid";
```

While displaying the result of above query, you can do this:

```
if Convert.ToInt32(dataRow("cnt")) > 0
   status = "Present";
else
   status = "Absent";
```